# Serial.println within a class in Arduino

Tags: c++, class, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to do `Serial.println()` within a class in the Arduino IDE. However, the compiler is saying that `Serial` was not declared in this scope. Here is the code:

Code in Menu.h

```
class Menu
{
    public:
        int options[4];

        void test() {
          Serial.println("here");
        }

    private:

};
```

Code in main file:

```
#include "Menu.h"

Menu menu;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    menu.test();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right `#include` is probably added automatically by Arduino to your `.pde`.  Try `#include <WProgram.h>` in the top of your `Menu.h`.

Comment: if you are using 1.0 WProgram.h has been renamed to Arduino.h http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code snippet is complete (if it isn't, please post a complete one) but it looks like you forgot to include the appropriate header file which declares the class `Serial`.